# Android Image Upload to server, HTTP Response is 200, but File is not uploaded

Tags: php, android, eclipse, http, xampp

Here's the php script that is on my server.

```
<?php
$target_path1 = "/Pictures/"
$target_path1 = $target_path1 . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $target_path1)) { 
    echo "Success";
} else {
    echo "fail";
}
?>
```

And this is my Android Java code:

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ImageUpload {
private int serverResponseCode = 0;
private String upLoadServerUri = "http://10.0.2.2/Pictures/UploadToServer.php";
private String imagepath = null;
Context context;

public ImageUpload(Context mcontext) {
    context = mcontext;
}

public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

    String fileName = sourceFileUri;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

        // dialog.dismiss();

        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + imagepath);

        return 0;

    } else {
        try {

            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                    sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

            // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            Toast.makeText(context, fileName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", /*fileName*/"test.jpg");

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                    + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                // dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                    + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                Toast.makeText(
                        context,
                        "Image Successfully Shuffled and Sent \n You will be notified once it is solved",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            // close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

            Toast.makeText(context, "MalformedURLException",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            Toast.makeText(context, "Got Exception : see logcat ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("Upload file to server Exception",
                    "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return serverResponseCode;

    }
}
```

}

I'm passing the sourceUri to upload from my application which is something like /sdcard/pictures/temp.jpg

Kindly help me the response is HTTP Response 200 but file is not there on server.

Using XAMP phpmyadmin.

Comment: This uploads with no problems, but AFAIK you can't retrieve uploaded file with getParameter("name") in java servlets, instead you get it by getInputStream(), so you need to find an equivlent method in php

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the response but I'm not using any getParameter. else can you please guide me with the correct code.

Comment: same problem here.. any solution

Answer (score 2):

**Java:**

```
public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        try {
            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploadedfile", sourceFileUri);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + sourceFileUri + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);


            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "+ serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                Log.e("uploadFile", "File Uploaded.");
                // Congrats!
            }

            //close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return serverResponseCode;

    } // End else block
}
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$target_path = "./uploads/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file " . basename($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]) . " has been uploaded";
} else {
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

It works!